# How can I add an else statement to this Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#start_quiz").click(function(){
    $("#start_quiz").fadeOut(0);
    $("#quiz_game").fadeIn('slow');

    $("#answer_button").click(function(){
        if($("#test").is(":checked")){
            $(".questions").fadeOut(200, function(){
                $('#correct_answer').fadeIn('slow');
            });
        };

    });

});
});
```

I have managed to get this jQuery code to work so that if the correct answer is in my form, it will fade out and display some text. I was wondering how I could design this so if any of the other four radio buttons were pressed, it could instead display other text (currently nothing happens). Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Hi there, do you have your buttons HTML to add to this?  Many of us will take it over to jsfiddle along with your script to work with.  It usually speeds up getting you an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#start_quiz").click(function () {
        $("#start_quiz").fadeOut(0);
        $("#quiz_game").fadeIn('slow');

        $("#answer_button").click(function () {
            if ($("#test").is(":checked")) {
                $(".questions").fadeOut(200, function () {
                    $('#correct_answer').fadeIn('slow');
                });
            } else {
                /* YOU WOULD PUT CODE HERE FOR INCORRECT ANSWER */
            }

        });

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/24DeT/

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("#test").is(":checked")){
            $(".questions").fadeOut(200, function(){
                $('#correct_answer').fadeIn('slow');
            });
}
else if($("#testotherone").is(":checked")){
            $(".questions").fadeOut(200, function(){
                $('#otherone_answer').fadeIn('slow');
            });
}
else if($("#testothertow").is(":checked")){
            $(".questions").fadeOut(200, function(){
                $('#othertow_answer').fadeIn('slow');
            });
}
```